# forever js is stopping another app

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

I have almost two identical Node JS projects which I start/stop using Forever JS. 
I am able to run them at the same time at two different ports **however**, when I do:

```
forever stop index.js
```

in one project folder, the `index.js` of the other project also stops running.

Does `forever` have a syntax to kill only a specific `index.js` process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the forever documentation [here](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever), you can do something like this with the `--uid` argument to give each one a unique name:

```
forever start --uid "production" index.js
forever stop production
```

Other things you could do:

1. Change the name of one of your `index.js` files.
2. Try using the full path to each `index.js` file to differentiate the two.